# Should this be a plugin or component solution? (Joomla!)

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, components

Based on the diagram below, would this be better achieved by creating a plugin for the core registration component of Joomla (3.0) or would it be better to create a custom component?

I envision that it would still use the user database table for common elements, but two separate relational tables depending on the type of user (client/vendor)

[image: Registration Map]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I definitely agree with @Brian. A plugin would be best suited for this as it would be best to extend the current registration form. We would also really appreciate it if you committed to the [Joomla Answers Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla?referrer=Ph_HGDW6OiEqU7r0cS-muA2) as you have over 200 rep :)

Answer (score 2):

I have to respectfully disagree with the other answer, this use case is practically the hallmark for creating a custom User plugin.

You could even use the existing #__user_profiles table to store any new data,  replicate the entirety of your use case scope to registration, profile viewing/editing and back-end user management with just the one plugin.

```
  <?php
  defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

  class plgUserCustomProfile extends JPlugin
  {

        function onContentPrepareData($context, $data) {
                //  This method loads all data for existing users
                //  By attaching variables to the $data object using the
                //  same naming convention as your form field definitions
                //  will facilitate automatic loading of values into forms
                return true;
        }

        function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
            // This method allows you to attach custom forms to core user form
            // I usually have different forms for profile view, profile edit
            // registration and back-end administration depending on needs
        }

        function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error) {
             // This method allows you to save edits to custom user fields
             return true;
        }

        function onUserAfterDelete($user, $success, $msg) {
             //  Here you get to delete all custom profile data when
             //  a user is deleted.
            return true;
        }


 }
```

The below link is a much more detailed explanation, but once built out; the control and flexibility it provides will make managing user profile data much easier.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Are you familiar with creating XML form definition files using Joomla methodology?

Are you implementing multi language support or Latisha definition files for your custom extensions?

Comment: Hi @brian bolli, Thanks for your input!.  I have been messing around with the user plugin for a while now, I'm actually responsible for a couple edits on that documentation you provided. I am beginning to wonder though if I should be thinking the word "and" instead of "or" for what I am trying to do.  My main concern are:

Comment: How to make the remainder of the form conditional based on which group the user assigns to themselve AND how that information will be communicated and displayed between the two groups (merchants viewing quotes from vendors, vendors viewing acceptance from merchants).  Basically, merchants and vendors input will be compared to provide automated quotes.

Comment: @cclark413 that logic can be encapsulated in fieldsets.  For example, you have one fieldset with your "core" options, including the selection of the group.  You put the remaining form fields for either group in their entirety into separate fieldsets, both hidden via JS when registration form is rendered.  Then us a JS handler to monitor the group field, showing the appropriate fieldset based on user selection.  Things will get hairy when trying to use required fields inside the hidden fieldsets client side, but that's a whole other question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definitions below your addition is better describes as a component.

http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(general_definitions)

#### Component

> Components are the largest and most complex extensions of them all; they can be seen as mini-applications. Most components have two parts: a site part and an administrator part. Every time a Joomla page loads, one component is called to render the main page body. For example, Content (com_content) is the component which handles the display of content; users can view at the frontend of your site and, as an administrator, you can edit the content. Components are the major portion of your page because a component is driven by a menu item and every menu item runs a component.

#### Module

> Modules are more lightweight and flexible extensions used for page rendering. These modules are mostly known as the “boxes” that are arranged around a component, for example: the login module. The footer is a module. Modules are assigned per menu item. So, you can decide to show or hide the logon module depending on which menu item the user is viewing. Sometimes modules are linked to components such as the “latest news” module which links to the com_content and displays links to the newest content items. However, modules do not need to be linked to components, as a matter of fact they don't even need to be linked to anything and can be just static HTML or text.

#### Plugin

> Plugins are more advanced extensions and are in essence event handlers. In the execution of any part of Joomla, be it the core, a module or a component, an event can be triggered. When an event is triggered, plugins that are registered with the application to handle that event execute. For example, a plugin could be used to intercept user-submitted articles and filter out bad words.